# Find the number of different words that can be formed from the letters of the word ‘TRIANGLE’ so that no vowels are together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a question that says: Find the number of different words that can be formed from the letters of the
word ‘TRIANGLE’ so that no vowels are together

I did this in the following way:
Number of ways in which TRIANGLE can be arranged -
Number of ways in which TRIANGLE can be arranged where 3 vowels are together -
Number of ways in which TRIANGLE can be arranged  where 2 vowels are together = 8! - (6!*3!) - (7!*2!*3) = 5760

The correct answer in my book is given to be 14400 calculated as:
xTxRxNxGxLx : x depicts spaces where vowels can be arranged and they are not together.
Therefore, Number of ways in which Consonants can be arranged*Number of ways in which vowels can be arranged  = 5!*6C3*3! = 14400.

Can anyone help me figure out why the method I follow isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying inclusive - exclusive principle

Making group with two vowels$(7!\times 2!\times 3)$ will cover also making group with three vowels $(6!\times3!)$

for example $TR(IA)ENGL$ arrangements of $(IA)$ together also has $E(IA)$  and $(IA)E$

$$8! - (7!\times 2!\times 3) + (6!\times3!)= 14400$$